# Search for contributions made in previous 4 months

Tags: contributions, search

I'm trying to search for contributions made in the previous 4 months.

Example - We are in October, but I want to be able to see if people have contributed since June 1.

I can search by previous month (Sept), previous 2 months (Aug), and the previous quarter (July), but am not sure how to search from the previous 4 months.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can always search by selecting "Choose Date Range" and entering dates manually (see screenshot below).

If you're looking to use a relative date filter because you need this to be in a report or smart group, then that date filter doesn't currently exist.

**However:** I am actively working on making it possible to create your own date filters ([CRM-16195](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16195))!  I am waiting on someone to review some [preliminary cleanup](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10941) I did a couple of weeks ago.  Once the cleanup is approved, I will submit a change so that custom date filters can be added by an extension.  I already have an extension written that will handle your scenario.

If you absolutely can't wait, and you're comfortable patching CiviCRM, contact me on https://chat.civicrm.org (@junglebird) and I'll give you a patch so you can do this today.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the update, it turns out I was misreading the dates I needed to search for, but it's nice to know that such a code is on it's way!

Comment: I also figured that a combination of 'contribution' last made smart groups and 'activity -> membership status changed' smart groups can fill in the gap.